# Ac Blower runs sometime

Tags: blower

My ac blower works great but sometimes when the ac unit cycles on again it doesn't work I have to turn off power for awhile then it works sometimes days before happening again.
I replaced capacitor and relay. There is no control board. When the unit is running when the blower doesn't work,  I check the wires going to to the motor from capacitor there is no power thanks for any help

Comment: You probably have a broken wire or open connection or a bad relay contact. Check all the connections and be sure they are all clean and free of corrosion. If you have push on connectors one at a time remove clean and put back. Be sure to take pictures before you start. If that does not fix it Please post pictures reasonably close to the wiring of each of the items ando and one showing all of it.

Comment: Brand/model of all the pieces involved would be helpful. Also, some pictures of all the wiring connections wouldn't hurt - someone might spot a connection that looks like it's worth checking on.